# Time removal and a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, time, where-clause

I have two questions for the same field.

1. I need to remove the time and just show the date from this A_received_date and I am using this caluclated field for it - DATEADD(DD,90,cd.A_RECEIVED_DATE)
2. Also need help with a where clause to pull only those accounts that's due in 5 days from this A_received_date

Thank you!!

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language that you are using.  That will help it get the attention of people knowledgeable about that language.

Answer (score 0):

1. To convert datetime to time use DATE()

```
select date(now());

+-------------+
| date(now()) |
+-------------+
| 2021-11-11  |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and where clause with interval

```
select * from my_table where my_date_column > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 5 day));
```

Comment: This is what worked for me for the date part...CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DD,90,cd.A_RECEIVED_DATE),120).  This is the date field I need to use in the where clause to look for accounts falling in the interval of those 5 days....tying to send an alert for the coming 5 days.